# image_url missing assets prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, sass, refinerycms

In the scss of RefineryCMS gem, they are targeting an image for background like this:

```
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background: #303030 image_url('refinery/page_bg.png') repeat;
}
```

And when is compiled, it will be like this:

```
background: #303030 image_url('refinery/page_bg.png') repeat;
```

But, page_bg.png is in the assets folder: `assets/refinery/page_bg.png`

If I try `www.mydomain.com/assets/refinery/page_bg.png` I can see the image
So, `image_url('refinery/page_bg.png')` in the compiled scss is missing the prefix `assets/`

How can I fix this?

I tried to create a folder in `public` folder named `refinery` and put `page_bg.png` inside it, but, I didn't work, and www.mydomain.com/refinery/page_bg.png won't show the image .

Is there a solution for this? any one can help? fixing the assets prefix is of course better, but, I don't mind using the public folder directly ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [asset-pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) config defines some directories as `asset` directories . This means the reference to the content in asset directories is without `assets` in front. For example , in most default configs the asset directories are : `app/assets` , `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` . You can place your `.png` background image in each of their subfolders with the name `image` and refer to it just like this : `background: url(your_image.png)` .

EDIT : According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/refinery-cms/xx85GnzdqCg), if deploying to Hiroku , there should be `sass-rails` included in the process of assets precompilation .

Comment: do you mean that if I removed 'refinery/' from image_url, it will be served from assets folder? if that's it, then how can I override the vendor scss to make this change?

Comment: No , `/refinery` is a subdirectory of `assets` . If the image is (for example) in `app/assets/refinery/images` , you can `url('refinery/images/yourimg.png`)`.

Comment: I see, but the problem is solved by pre-compiling scss files using a heroku settings, if you are interested, please see here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/refinery-cms/xx85GnzdqCg

Comment: Interesting , I find it valuable , thank you. Do you allow to include it in the answer ?

Comment: Almost went crazy. This was the answer, excellent source linking!

Comment: But when you find the solution it feels good :) Happy to hear it.